# Mockito, jUnit, testable class has @Named annotation, how to pass value to it when testing

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a piece of code that I'm struggling with at work and I would really like to learn more about of how to overcome this type of problem.

```html
public class SomeTestableClass  {

 @Inject(optional = true)
 @Named("balance.period.tm")
 protected String balance;

 public void save(Connection connection, Report r) throws Exception {
  if ( 1 == 1 ) {
   someObject.someMethod(param1, param2, balance) {
   // do something, etc...
   }
  }
 }
}
```

As I'm not allowed to post any business code here but I created a rough idea of the problem I'm facing. Sorry if its bit confusing in any way, I'm still very green. So there is a "String balance" that gets a value from one properties files.

When the code gets to someObject.someMethod() then I'm getting a nullpointer exception because "balance" is null. I'm trying to use that same method with verify().

How could I possibly pass value to it when testing or how could I get around this problem.

Cheers.

Comment: What dependency injection framework are you using?

Comment: As a unit test, you can use a setter method (or make the field visible to the test). If you go this way, make sure to document why you make the field accessible. Another option is to extend the class and use a getter inside the `save` method, so that the overwritten getter provides the value that you need to have in the test. If you want to use injection in the test (which then is not a standard unit test!), you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

You typically would have a `setBalance(String val)` setter for that property, but if you didn't, you could still access a "protected" property directly from your test if your test is running under the same package name.

```
SomeTestableClass testable=new SomeTestableClass();
testable.balance="123.45";
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why I didn't I think about setter... Cheers